# Rails helper method with external classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am going to try and explain this the best way I can...so here we go...

Here is my old(working) controller for truck.  What it does is it sorts by columns and asc/desc orders which works as intended.

```
class TrucksController < ApplicationController
  # GET /trucks
  # GET /trucks.json
  require 'sort_methods'
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
  def index
    @trucks = Truck.search(params[:search]).order(SortMethods.sort_column(Truck, "truck_no", params[:sort]) + " " + SortMethods.sort_direction(params[:direction]))

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @trucks }
    end
  end

private

  def sort_column
    Truck.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "truck_no"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
end
```

From what I understand the helper_method here is called so that when page is passed with no arguments, it has a default it can revert to and sort methods below are the methods that cause the default behavior.  All this works as intended, I can load pages and sort.

Now the @ trucks is calling a class in lib which has identical methods to my sort_methods because I call those methods multiple times and i'm trying to DRY code this.  This works, still because I've done the class in this way:

```
class SortMethods
  def self.sort_column(table, field, sort)
    table.column_names.include?(sort) ? sort : field
  end

  def self.sort_direction(direction)
    %w[asc desc].include?(direction) ? direction : "asc"
  end
end
```

Alright so code like this works as intended, the problem is that I am repeating sort methods twice, in my controller and in the SortMethods class.  What I would like to do is set the default for the helper class using the SortMethods but if I try to call it using this code:

```
helper_method :SortMethods.sort_column(Truck, "truck_no", params[:sort]), SortMethods.sort_direction(params[:direction])
```

I receive following message:

```
undefined local variable or method `sort_column' for #<#<Class:0x1a3a780>:0x1852f08>
```

My assumption is one of the variables I am passing in is nil, I can't figure out which one and how would I go about it to avoid this problem?  Is there another way I can default to this if no parameters are set in place.  I also tried moving helper in index but that gives me this error:

```
undefined method `sort_column' for :SortMethods:Symbol
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helper_method makes given method accessible inside controller views. Hence, you don't need to specify those SortMethods methods as a helper, because they are not part of the controller. You should be able to call them in a view like

```
SortMethods.sort_column(blah)
```

Also, where do you keep definition of SortMethods class? If it is in a file sort_methods.rb anywhere in app folder, you can skip require on the top, as rails will automatically search for it (it is a part of constant_missing method)

Comment: I thank you for reading my novel/question there.  I am a little confused with your explanation.  The way I have coded was based on many examples I found online and went with best practices that these examples recommended to prevent things such sql injections and other.  So I have to admit that I do not 100% fully understand how this works hence why I posted this here and gave the explanation of how I understand it.  If I don't call the helper inside the controller the way I do and i use the url with just localhost:3000/trucks I get undefined local variable error.  How can I get around this?

Comment: By what you said about helper, I understood is that the line of code is there to allow the helper to have access to methods in my controller.  Correct?  You also mentioned something about including it in the view, do I put in the Trucks view before the table that displays it is called or?  I tried this: <% SortMethods.sort_direction(params[:direction]) %> in the view and took out helper in the controller and I got the same error.

Comment: You can read about helper_method here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method. It simply allows you to call given controller method when rendering the view. If you don't call helper_method :sort_column, you will get no variable error, because you are trying to call controller method which is normally not accessible inside the view.

This mean, that you can get rid off those two private methods from controller, and then you need to change existing calls to this methods inside a view, so they are calling SortMethods.sort_column method instead.

Comment: Oh ok, That makes a lot more sense now, thank you for that link.  So how would I make the methods that are in a class file which is located in the lib, how would I make those methods accessible to view?  I tried using helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction in the controller but it didn't seem to work, probably because that class is not associated to a view, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: I personally would move this file from lib to a helper and rename it to sort_methods.rb

Rails works in many weird ways, and that's one of my favourite - when you call a constant (SortMethods) which is uknown at the moment, rails will try to find file with appropriate name (sort_method.rb) in one of load locations, load it and then retry to access constant. If that fails it raise no constant exception.
Hence there is no need to put require statement as long as you keep correct file naming convention.

Comment: ok and if I do that how do I access these methods from a controller?

Comment: Same way as you do now. :) Once a class is declared in a right file in a right place it is accessible everywhere.

Comment: well, I had to add include MyHelper  for it to work, that is what I was asking about.  I got it to work though, added it to the helper and calling it from there now.